# Spawning a Process launches another instance of Tkinter - Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing to a program I made for my job, and I'm running into issues.  Please see the simplified code below; when I launch a process, it launches another instance of the gui; when I close that instance, the cpu_intensive function is processed.  It's my first time using Tkinter and threads and processes so there might be more than one problem in there ;-)  Thanks for looking into this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


source_queue = Queue()


def thread_launch():
    """launches a thread to keep the gui responsive"""
    thread1 = Thread(target=process_engine)
    return thread1.start()


def process_engine():
    """spawns processes and populates the queue"""
    p1 = Process(target=cpu_intensive, args=(source_queue,))
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=cpu_intensive, args=(source_queue,))
    p2.start()

    for i in range(10):
        source_queue.put(i)
        print "Added item", i, "to queue"

    source_queue.close()
    source_queue.join_thread()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()


def cpu_intensive(item_toprocess):
    """function to be multiprocessed"""
    print "Processed: item", item_toprocess.get()


class Application:

    def __init__(self, master):
        """defines the gui"""
        self.master = master
        self.process_button = Button(self.master,
                                     text="Process",
                                     command=thread_launch)
        self.process_button.pack(padx=100, pady=100)


def __main__():
    """launches the program"""
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == __main__():
    __main__()
```

Comment: Try:
`if __name__ == "__main__":`
instead.

Comment: And it works, of course, it makes much more sense!  Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

instead.  The previous version was calling main but checking the returned value (`None` in this case).  The problem was (I suspect you are on Windows) that the child process was also calling `main` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Confirmed, I am on Windows.  Thanks again, I spent a lot of time reworking my code because of this ;-)

Comment: The problem with the `main` occurs on Windows with `multiprocessing` because Windows does not implement `fork()` in the same way that UNIX/Linux does.  So when `multiprocessing` creates a child it runs `main` again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's great to finally understand what was happening.